# URL encode variable in Jmeter

Tags: url, automation, httprequest, jmeter

I need to encode a variable in `Jmeter`, but it isn't a parameter. For example:

`URL path: /folder/guest/id;token=${token}/profile?details=yes`

I want to encode the `${token}` variable, and only the token variable. I know that you can select `encode` in the parameters section, but this isn't a parameter.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: In my case, ? is getting encoded to "\udd03" like this. Could you please suggest any workaround ?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

JMeter as of version 2.10 now includes a urlencode function.

```
${__urlencode(${token})}
```

See http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html

Answer (score 8):

The best way I found to do this was to use a `JavaScript` function:

```
${__javaScript(encodeURIComponent('${token}'))}
```

So the request would be:

```
/folder/guest/id;token= ${__javaScript(encodeURIComponent('${token}'))}/profile?details=yes
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are using JMeter GUI -- HTTP Request, you can check the encode option:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

__urlencode function works fine. It is just we need to put token variable in
  quotes. i.e.  ${__urlencode('${token}')}