# JMeter intermittently failing to parse URL variables while load testing

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

While load testing with JMeter I am attempting to send 1000 requests in one second. The issue is that I need to send the access token aquired from each previous login. While doing so I am getting the following error:

> java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 67: https://greenback-api.com/api/subscribers/getSavings/${USER_ID}?access_token=${AUTH_TOKEN}

Typical under a low load JMETER has no problem transforming the variables into a valid url likeso:

```
api.com/api/subscribers/getSavings/4?access_token=443hrr4938rh9ghreughughtrugtrgt4
```

Is there a way to force JMETER to render the url variables before issuing a get request even under a high load?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like sometimes `${USER_ID}` and `${AUTH_TOKEN}` are not returned by login (or whatever sets them). As a result JMeter will use the expression `${...}` as is. And the characters `{}` are indeed invalid for URI (they have to be encoded).

Another option is that `${USER_ID}` or `${AUTH_TOKEN}` really contain some characters invalid for URI and that need to be encoded.

So you may need to

1. [URL Encode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14593183/url-encode-variable-in-jmeter) your `${AUTH_TOKEN}` (and possibly `${USER_ID}`)
2. Make stricter checking upon login completion (and any other operations that fill `${USER_ID}` or `${AUTH_TOKEN}`) to make sure they don't proceed to the following operations if the value was not returned.