# Issue when posting URL in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have HTTP sampler,from where post processor --regex extractor was used to get the value of id1

```
id1":"0501475486-2017-10-13 14:10:59.834"
```

This id1 when passing in another HTTPSampler its failing (since the space in id1 value is becoming encode with %20 i believe)

```
/paymentinstructions/single/sepa/TPS;${id1}
/paymentinstructions/single/sepa/TPS;0501475486-2017-10-13%2014:10:59.834
```

how to achieve this working?

i tried directly hardcoding the value in the URL,but when the request is going it is treating as %20 again

```
/paymentinstructions/single/sepa/TPS;0501475486-2017-10-13 14:10:59.834
/paymentinstructions/single/sepa/TPS;0501475486-2017-10-13%2014:10:59.834
```

please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [URL encode variable in Jmeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14593183/url-encode-variable-in-jmeter)

Comment: Can you show your HTTP Request ?